# Syntax array for mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, postgresql, go

what syntax for add data Array into database,
i found for postgresql is : pg.Array

```
 // "ins" is the SQL insert statement
ins := "INSERT INTO posts (title, tags) VALUES ($1, $2)"

// "tags" is the list of tags, as a string slice
tags := []string{"go", "goroutines", "queues"}

// the pq.Array function is the secret sauce
_, err = db.Exec(ins, "Job Queues in Go", pq.Array(tags))
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points here that I'll break up, which mostly comes from lack of clarity in your question:

#### First

`pq.Array` is used to convert array values into safe lists in PostgreSQL, such as the following statement:

```
db.Query(`SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = ANY($1)`, pq.Array([]int{235, 401}))
```

Where the resulting query is:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id = ANY(235, 401)
```

This is intended to help you safely craft query values irrelevant of types, from lists, which is not how you're using it with your question.

#### Second

If you're simply trying to marshal the value into a comma-separated list in your database column, ie:

```
| title   | tags                 |
|---------|----------------------|
| my post | go,goroutines,queues |
```

You don't need a special function within the SQL driver. You simply need to create the value, and let the prepared statement do its thing:

```
tags := []string{"go, goroutines, queues"}
q := "INSERT INTO posts (title, tags) VALUES ($1, $2)"
_, _ = db.Exec(q, "mypost", strings.Join(tags, ","))
```

#### Third

You'd probably be even BETTER served, using relationships within MySQL to accomplish what you're doing:

posts

```
| id | title   |
|----|---------|
| 1  | my post |
```

tags

```
| id | tag        |
|----|------------|
| 1  | go         |
| 2  | goroutines |
| 3  | queues     |
```

posts_tags

```
| posts_id | tags_id |
|----------|---------|
| 1        | 1       |
| 1        | 2       |
| 1        | 3       |
```

This will help you save space by not saving duplicate data, and remove the need to understand the serialization method within the database (plus, this is what relational databases *do*). Then, when you select the table, you can craft `JOIN` statements to retrieve the data as needed. I highly recommend reading up on many to many relationships within MySQL.

Comment: This data model is way overnormalized and sacifices hard to acquire performance (JOINs are more expensive than just reading a field) for relatively cheap disk space. Given the prices for storage today, that is a bad tradeoff.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I actually disagree with that statement entirely. Disk is cheap these days, and so is computing. Yes this over complicates a simple data structure, but I wouldn't imagine he would only be building an application that only contains these features. Starting with good practices ultimately allows you to build a better application. "What tags does everyone use" is infinitely harder to answer in the previous approach.

Comment: There is a difference between computing and performance. You can scale computing as much as you like - if a query is more expensive than another one, it is going to take longer. And without proper use cases which justify it, there is no need to complicate a data model.